# How to store the input xml data in to map using XSLT2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm tring to store the input xml data into map and how to save that data.

Input XML:

```
    <person>
     <value id="123">
        <name>abc</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </value>
    <value id="456">
        <name>xyz</name>
        <age>80</age>
    </value>
    <value id="1235">
        <name>abcfg</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </value>
    <value id="4568">
        <name>xyzd</name>
        <age>80</age>
    </value>
    </person>
```

Output File:

```
xyzd|80
abcfg|25
```

Is there any way to possible to store the data into map object and print that data into output?

Comment: Huh?  Where is your XSL?  Why do you need a map, and where is this map hosted?

Comment: Is not clear what you mean by 'map', remember that you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31119493/edit) to add more info. Are you talking about map as a data structure of a specific programing language? If so, please tell us what programing language.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input XML,

```
<person>
  <value id="123">
    <name>abc</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </value>
  <value id="456">
    <name>xyz</name>
    <age>80</age>
  </value>
  <value id="1235">
    <name>abcfg</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </value>
  <value id="4568">
    <name>xyzd</name>
    <age>80</age>
  </value>
</person>
```

the following XSLT, which will work with both XSLT 2.0 and 1.0,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name,'|',age,'&#xa;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce a mapping output file,

```
abc|25
xyz|80
abcfg|25
xyzd|80
```

of the format requested.